# Why does not valiant's reduction show NP=RP?

Tags: complexity-theory, counting

Valiant converts $SAT$ formula to a $0/1$ matrix such that $Permanent$ of the matrix is $4^m\#SAT$.

We know $Permanent$ can be approximated to $1+\epsilon$ factor with probability $1-\frac1\delta$ in time $poly(m|\epsilon|^{-1}\log\frac1\delta)$.

Why does not these two help me tell when number of witnesses to $SAT$ formula is $0$ in randomized polynomial time?

What do I miss?

Comment: You can determine whether a non-negative matrix has permanent zero in polynomial time, using bipartite perfect matching. So I doubt your description of Valiant’s reduction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you state, Valiant shows how to construct, given a CNF $\varphi$, a polynomial size matrix whose permanent is a (known) multiple of the number of satisfying assignments of $\varphi$. Unfortunately, this matrix is not non-negative.

Given a non-negative matrix, you can determine whether its permanent is zero or not using an algorithm for bipartite perfect matching; and you can efficiently estimate its value. The same doesn't hold for general matrices.

Valiant further shows how to construct, given a CNF $\varphi$, a polynomial size 0/1 matrix, from whose permanent you can deduce the number of satisfying assignments of $\varphi$. However, the formula is not as simple as before, and in particular, neither bipartite perfect matching nor the efficient permanent estimation algorithms can determine whether $\varphi$ is satisfiable or not.

For details of a later version of this last reduction, see Section 5.1 of Ben-Dor and Halevi, [Zero-One Permanent is #P-Complete, A Simpler Proof](https://shaih.github.io/pubs/01perm.pdf).

Comment: As I understand we get a $\mathbb Z$ matrix with permanent $4^{3m}\#\phi$ where $m$ is number of clauses in $n$ variable formula $\phi$ and then a $\{0,1\}$ matrix with $Perm\equiv4^{3m}\#\phi\bmod 2^{m'+1}$ at some $m'\gg m$?

Comment: Right, something of this sort.

Comment: I am not understanding the non-triviality in formula for second reduction. If $\#\mbox{perfect-matchings}=2^{cm}\#\phi$ can't we decide no matchings and hence no witnesses?

Comment: The formula for the second reduction is not what you state. It is more complicated.

Comment: Could you point me to theorem in Valiant's paper https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0304397579900446/pdf?md5=70d07916cd850c9d82303f6fcacb63e6&pid=1-s2.0-0304397579900446-main.pdf?

Comment: I have a reference, Ben-Dor and Halevi. I’m less interested in historical matters.

Comment: Section 5.1 in Ben-Dor and Halevi has no 0/1 matrix.

Comment: I encourage you to read the entire paper. Do the work.

Comment: You can find the 0/1 matrix in Section 5.3. Also, according to Ben-Dor and Halevi, their construction combines the work of Valiant with that of Zanko (1991).